# Ruby Mechanize, save html as file after filling a form

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I want to save the html after filling a form. lets say:

```
page.form.field.value = 'testing'
page.save 'test.html'
```

the generated test.html file don't have the modified value attribute

```
 <input name='something' value=''>
```

I'm expecting:

```
 <input name='something' value='testing'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use dom functions for that:

```
page.at('[name=something]')['value'] = 'testing'
```

In other words there's no reason to expect that changes to the Form fields will update the dom.